# Hibernate Windows PC from Linux

Tags: windows, shutdown

To shutdown a Windows PC from Linux I use:

```
net rpc shutdown -I 192.168.1.123 -U userName%password
```

and it works perfectly. To hibernate I try:

```
net rpc shutdown -h -I 192.168.1.123 -U userName%password
```

and it does nothing. It returns:

```
Usage: net rpc shutdown
```

If I try use another "Windows shutdown" parameters (for example -C 'comment') it works

Is it possibile hibernate from remote?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [no such flag](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/net.8.html) as `-h`. Samba's `net rpc shutdown` doesn't support hibernation yet.

Instead you could try [WinEXE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) though I'm not sure if it still works with modern versions of Linux and Windows.

Also `net rpc` can start and stop services: `net rpc service stop SERVICENAME -I IPADDRESS -U USERNAME%PASSWORD`, so you could create a Windows service which does only one thing and that's hibernating. That could be done using [srvany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/create-user-defined-service), [srvany-ng](https://github.com/birkett/srvany-ng) or [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/).

Comment: Ok, good workaround. Thanks

Comment: @cldparisi If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.